# Validate and Apply schema to a list in python

Tags: python, list, schema

Basically I have a list of list as shown below and it should follow schema something like

[ [ID,value1,value2,value3] ]

```
[[105, 'A', 'B'],
[102, 'B', 'C'],
[111, 'A', 'B', 'C'],
[106, 'B'],
[100, 'A', 'C']]
```

I wanted to achieve a result like this

```
[[105, 'A', 'B', 'null'],
[102, 'null','B', 'C'],
[111, 'A', 'B', 'C'],
[106, 'null','B','null'],
[100, 'A','null', 'C']]
```

Its like I have a schema that the list has to follow ,if the particular value is not available it should be replaced by null.I can write code with conditional statements but it is not a scalable option. I am trying to work on few packages such as schema 0.5.0 and marshmallow they are used just to validate whether the particular list or dictionary can follow a schema or not (T/F). But I trying to replace values if they are not found.

Comment: Notice how your answer has a string null rather than a null value.

Comment: Does the longest sublist hold all values?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Essentially map each list to a new list with either the value or None.

```
alist = [[105, 'A', 'B'],
         [102, 'B', 'C'],
         [111, 'A', 'B', 'C'],
         [106, 'B'],
         [100, 'A', 'C']]

alist = map(lambda x: [x[0] ,
                  "A" if "A" in x else "None",
                  "B" if "B" in x else "None",
                  "C" if "C" in x else "None"], alist)
```

alternatively: You can just have a list of values the list should have and map that list instead.

```
values =   ["A","B", "C", "D"]
alist = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + #ID 
                            list(map(lambda y: y if y in x else "None", values)), alist))
```